# JFrame pack() method

Tags: java, rendering, graphics, jframe

I was developing a game using java AWT and I realized that the position of pack() method can influence rendering. For instance:

**Frame Class**

```
public class Frame {
    public Frame(int width, int height, Game game) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Practice Game");
        
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        frame.pack();  // pack method is used before adding game component to frame
        frame.add(game);
    }
}
```

**Game Class**

```
public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {
    // Dimension
    public static final int WIDTH = 320;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 320;

    public Game() {
        new Frame(WIDTH, HEIGHT, this);

        menu = new Menu(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        start();
    }

    public void render() {
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();

        if (bs == null) {
            this.createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }

        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) bs.getDrawGraphics();

        menu.render(g);

        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Game();
    }
```

This set of code results in making an empty frame without any component displayed.

However, when I tried putting pack method after I added game component to the JFrame, it successfully displayed what I intended to display.

I heard that pack() method is used to pack the components within the JFrame based on the component’s preferred sizes. However, I don't understand how the position of pack() method could influence the entire rendering (only displaying an empty frame).

---

Also, the actual size of frame doesn't match the dimension that I assigned to the frame. To illustrate this:

**Menu Class**

```
public class Menu {
    public Menu(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        squareSize = 64;

        squareRowNum = height / squareSize;
        squareColNum = width / squareSize;
    }

    public void render(Graphics2D g) {
        drawBackground(g);
    }

    public void drawBackground(Graphics2D g) {
        for (int i = 0; i < squareRowNum; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < squareColNum; j++) {
                g.setColor(Color.black);
                g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
                g.drawRect(j * squareSize, i * squareSize, squareSize, squareSize);
                g.setColor(Color.white);
                g.fillRect(j * squareSize, i * squareSize, squareSize, squareSize);
            }
        }
    }
```

When running these 3 classes together, it display:

[image]

The rectangle box at the bottom are cut off instead of fully displaying 5 * 5 rectangles (each rectangles has dimension of 64, 64 and the frame size is supposedly 320, 320). I assumed that it's because I'm using mac. I think this can also be fixed using pack() method but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

You must be careful with setting the size... if you set the size from the JFrame you override the ability of `pack()`.

You should ONLY set the size of the content, not of the JFrame itself.
this pic shows you the difference between content size and JFrame size:
[image]